# What is a Honey Malt, and is there an alternative malt to replace it?

Tags: malt

A recipe I'd like to try has a small proportion of *Honey Malt* as part of its grain bill. I've looked around supply sites and haven't found one that supplies this malt. I'm in New Zealand, so this might be a regional difference.

What is Honey Malt, and are there any alternative malts that I can use to replace it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a yummy malt made by Gambrinus Malting, in my home province of British Columbia, Canada.

If you have access to Brumalt, I understand that that is similar.  If not, maybe Melanoidin.  If not that, a light crystal, around 25.

As you say the Honey Malt is a small proportion of the bill, I don't think you can go too far off.  I've made beers with about 10% Honey Malt, and I don't think a substitute would result in the same beer with those, except maybe Brumalt.